# Filter the output of Logger.log to only show specific parts

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a simple function (shown below) that lists all the existing schema values for a Google Workspace domain. I would like to only retrieve specific items.

This is my function:

```
function listSchema() {

const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
const sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Domain Schema");
const schemaSafeName = sheet.getRange(4,2).getValue();

try{
    Logger.log(AdminDirectory.Schemas.get('my_customer',schemaSafeName));
  }
  catch(error){
    const {code, message} = error.details;

    if(code === 400 || code === 404 || code === 409 || code === 412){
      console.log("Error 400 or 404 or 409 or 412");
    }
    else {
      console.log(`${code} - ${message}`);
    }
  }  
}
```

The Logger.log (prettified and commented) output is as follows:

```
{
 etag="eObIY8zBQ9kCV0dcsWouNipdJvA0", // DON'T WANT THIS
  
  displayName=Test Schema Group,
      
   fields=
     [
      {
       fieldId=87mf1ADjQwuyvPaKPIa2uw==, // DON'T WANT THIS
       readAccessType=ADMINS_AND_SELF,
       displayName=Test Field1,
       fieldType=BOOL,
       fieldName=Test_Field1,
       etag="eObIY8zBQ9kCV03CoXVqpKE7PI", // DON'T WANT THIS
       multiValued=false,
       kind=admin#directory#schema#fieldspec // DON'T WANT THIS
      },
      {
       multiValued=false,
       fieldName=Test_Field2,
       displayName=Test Field2,
       etag="eObIY8zBQ9kCSggLJvV_R8EVdhq8S0O3A", // DON'T WANT THIS
       fieldType=BOOL,
       fieldId=7pRb-wPQQE2cyVvniaJA==, // DON'T WANT THIS
       readAccessType=ADMINS_AND_SELF,
       kind=admin#directory#schema#fieldspec // DON'T WANT THIS
      }
      ],
          
  schemaId=tAq6fq92Qn-6egbHjFFkug==, // DON'T WANT THIS
  kind=admin#directory#schema, // DON'T WANT THIS
  schemaName=Test_Schema_Group133
}
```

`

*Note: every time I run it the order is different, so I guess using something to retrieve parts of the output using some sort of index would not work. But I may be wrong.*

I'd like to get a "filtered" Logger.log output as follows (**edited to show nested schema**):
`

```
{
 [
  {
   displayName=Test Schema Group 1,
    fields=
     [
      {
       readAccessType=ADMINS_AND_SELF,
       displayName=Test Field1,
       fieldType=BOOL,
       fieldName=Test_Field1,
       multiValued=false,
      },
      {
       multiValued=false,
       fieldName=Test_Field2,
       displayName=Test Field2,
       fieldType=BOOL,
       readAccessType=ADMINS_AND_SELF,
      }
      ],    
    schemaName=Test_Schema_Group1
   },
{
   displayName=Test Schema Group 2,
    fields=
     [
      {
       readAccessType=ADMINS_AND_SELF,
       displayName=Test Field1,
       fieldType=BOOL,
       fieldName=Test_Field1,
       multiValued=false,
      },
      {
       multiValued=false,
       fieldName=Test_Field2,
       displayName=Test Field2,
       fieldType=BOOL,
       readAccessType=ADMINS_AND_SELF,
      }
      ],
   schemaName=Test_Schema_Group2
  }
 ]
}
```

`

So, basically, I'd like the output to ignore the values of "fieldId", "kind", and "etag".

Additionally - and ideally -, I'd also like to have the option to only the value, without the name, such as: "Test Schema Group" instead of "displayName=Test Schema Group". This way I can then push those values to a Google Sheet, with a pre-defined title for each row, without the need to filter it (using the Index function).

If I understand how to do this, I can then adapt it to get only any given value. I hope...

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you need to handpick what you want anyway, you might as well do it like this:

```js
var data = {
  etag: "eObIY8zBQ9kCV0dcsWouNipdJvA0",
  displayName: "Test Schema Group",
  fields: [{
      fieldId: "87mf1ADjQwuyvPaKPIa2uw==",
      readAccessType: "ADMINS_AND_SELF",
      displayName: "Test Field1",
      fieldType: "BOOL",
      fieldName: "Test_Field1",
      etag: "eObIY8zBQ9kCV03CoXVqpKE7PI",
      multiValued: false,
      kind: "admin#directory#schema#fieldspec"
    },
    {
      multiValued: false,
      fieldName: "Test_Field2",
      displayName: "Test Field2",
      etag: "eObIY8zBQ9kCSggLJvV_R8EVdhq8S0O3A",
      fieldType: "BOOL",
      fieldId: "7pRb-wPQQE2cyVvniaJA==",
      readAccessType: "ADMINS_AND_SELF",
      kind: "admin#directory#schema#fieldspec"
    }
  ],
  schemaId: "tAq6fq92Qn-6egbHjFFkug==",
  kind: "admin#directory#schema",
  schemaName: "Test_Schema_Group133"
}
var ret = {};
if(data.schemaName == "Test_Schema_Group133"){
ret.displayName = data.displayName;
ret.schemaName = data.schemaName;
var fields = [];
for (var f of data.fields) {
  var obj = {};
  obj.readAccessType = f.readAccessType;
  obj.displayName = f.displayName;
  obj.fieldType = f.fieldType;
  obj.fieldName = f.fieldName;
  obj.multiValued = f.multiValued;
  fields.push(obj);
}
ret.fields = fields;
}
console.log(ret);
```

There are alternatives with `Object.keys()` or `Object.getOwnPropertyNames()`. But they will do essentially the same...

Comment: Hi @Ricardas, thanks for your answer. I have tested it, and it gives me the exact same output. Furthermore, even if the output were different, this way I would have to manually enter even more data. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Not sure how you tested it, but just run the snippet and the output is exactly as you wanted it to have. Your final output is object `ret` in my example. I'm not sure, that I understand what you mean with "manually enter even more data". If you have to handpick data out of object you will ALWAYS  have to manually define what data you want to pick out. There is no universal way around it... If you are picking more data then you are ignoring, then defining what has to be ignored may be more elegant way...

Comment: I tested it by running the function. And regarding the manual part of entering data: the plan is to use a variable (the name of the custom schema) that is retrieved from a Google Sheet cell. Then the script would list the output for that specific schema. And, ideally, I would be able to get only some values, because other values are irrelevant.

Comment: Sorry, I was testing it with the wrong function. My mistake. I will test it again now, with the correct function and let you know how it went.

Comment: It works. Sorry about that. Now the question is if I can just get the values, without the type.

Comment: What type do you mean? If you want to extract data just from some objects according to "custom schema name". Then you do that by defining `if` condition beforehand. If condition meets your schema name it processes the data and returns the extracted data, if not it ignores it. I added `if` condition to the snippet.

Comment: It's more like this: I have a few cell is the spreadsheet, titled "Schema Name", "Field Type", etc., and I'd like to get only the value for those fields, instead of getting the pair "title: value". I understand that for this I may have to use several "queries" but that would be OK. I just need to understand how to get the values only. For the top-level values I was able to do this by using "console.log(ret.schemaName);" but for the nested values I wasn't able to figure it out yet. In any case, your help was already great :-)

Comment: I think I got it. I used "console.log(data.fields[1].fieldType );". As the fields have no name, I figured I had to use the [1] (or another index) to get it. This is going well. Again, thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: if you know exactly what entry you are looking for in `fields` you can use index as you described. If you want to get values only, you only can get them as strings or array of strings, not as object anymore. You can do it with my function with small modifications.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250037/discussion-between-nuno-miguel-and-ricardas).